# Swift: Public int being incremented multiple times? Why?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have a weird problem and I have no idea what is causing it. I'm working in Swift here and I have in app purchases set up for my sprite kit game in a separate view controller that comes over my SKScene temporarily. When the user touches out of the in app purchase view controller, an unwind segue brings the user back to the game.

The in app purchases are consumable and all work well, except I'm having a very odd problem with a public variable that I need to alter when one IAP is bought.

I have a public int named `lives` that is set at the beginning of my game to 1. It is output through a label to the user using this: `livesCountLabel.text = "\(lives)"`

When the in app purchase is purchased, I call the following method:

```
func iap1Func() { //This func does the thing that they payed for

    print("YOU JUST BOUGHT A LIFE")
    lives++

}
```

This should increment the public `lives` variable by 1. I have checked that it does this using `println`s. Because the user accesses the IAPs through the pause screen I update the lives label in my resume function:

```
func deletePauseScreen() {

        pauseScreen.removeFromParent()

        restartButton.removeFromParent()
        resumeButton.removeFromParent()
        homeButton.removeFromParent()
        iapButton.removeFromParent()


        livesCountLabel.text = "\(lives)"
    }
```

And this works the first time, as in if the user's life count is 1 and they buy the IAP, when they return to the game their life count is 2. Also, if the user stays on the IAP view controller and keeps buying the IAP, `lives` goes up by 1 like it should - 1, 2, 3, etc.

The problem is that if the user goes back to the game, then comes back to the IAP screen and buys another life, `lives` goes up by 2. And the next time up by 3, by 4, etc. I have no idea what is causing this because `lives++` should just make `lives` go up by 1 each time. The IAP func is also only being called one time- I checked- so that is not the issue.

What's happening here? What should I do differently? Is there any update function I could write to make sure lives increments by 1 each time the IAP is bought?

EDIT:

The `iap1Func` is being called through a UIButton that I create here:

```
//IAPs button1 set up

        let iap1Image = "iapBtn1"
        let iap1BtnImage = UIImage(named: iap1Image)
        let iapButton1 = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)

        iapButton1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, screenSize.width * (180/320), screenSize.height * (41/568))
        iapButton1.center = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * (195/320), screenSize.height * (50/568)) //These x,y actually control position

        iapButton1.setBackgroundImage(iap1BtnImage, forState: .Normal)
        iapButton1.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        iapButton1.addTarget(self, action: "iap1Action:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

And through this function within my IAP code:

```
func iap1Action(sender:UIButton!)
{
    print("Trigger IAP 1")

    for product in list {
        let prodID = product.productIdentifier
        if(prodID == "saviors.iap1") {
            p = product
            buyProduct()
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I would create the didSet method for your lives property and add a breakpoint inside to detect when and by whom it is increased. From Apple documentation about the didSet method: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html